# gcc optimisation effect on structure size

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

Say I have a large struct, which includes other struct, etc. Would `gcc -os` or any other gcc optimisation switch change the way it's stored in memory? I.e. would it pack the structure so as to squeeze out some extra space?

thanks,

Comment: Have you tried? I bet you didn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in order change the native platform alignment for a structure in `gcc` you would have to explicitly use the `__attribute__((packed))` or `__attribute__((align X))` compiler directives, or other `gcc` command-line switches that specifically direct the compiler to change the native-platform alignment for data-structures.

Also, packing a structure with mixed data-types so that all the data-members may not be aligned on a proper word-boundary in memory actually will be **slower** for accessing a data-member at runtime, not faster.  This is because the compiler will have to unpack the structure back to the native alignment for the platform before accessing the data-member.

Comment: That's not the only way - there are command line switches too, e.g. `-malign=...` and you may get differences between e.g. `-m32` and `-m64`.

Comment: I prefer `#pragma pack` over `__attribute__` stuff.  Mostly because i never liked the attribute syntax, but also partially because the pragma pack syntax is fairly similar between compilers that support it.

Answer (score 3):

No, this should not happen - so long as you have the same alignment and packing options for all your code modules then they should work correctly together even if compiled with different optimisation levels,

Comment: If you had different layouts generated by differing `‑O` settings for example, then code generated in one translation unit might not match the layout expected in another translation unit when structs / classes are published and the published declaration is used in another file. It would be a nightmare, so you see why this isn't an option, as the previous poster pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I can see how aligning structs (by padding them) could lead to shorter code (no cross-boundary word addressing -> fewer load/stores)

**`-Os`** optimizes for binary size (i.e. most commonly referred to as code size) *not* memory compression